# Text Manipulation using sed or AWK

Tags: bash, awk, sed, var

I get the following result in my script when I run it against my services. The result differs depending on the service but the text pattern showing below is similar. The result of my script is assigned to var1. I need to extract data from this variable

```
$var1=HOST1*prod*gem.dot*serviceList : svc1 HOST1*prod*kem.dot*serviceList : svc3, svc4    HOST1*prod*fen.dot*serviceList : svc5, svc6
```

I need to strip the name of the service list from $var1. So the end result should be printed on separate  line as follow:

```
svc1 
svc2
svc3
svc4
svc5
svc6
```

Can you please help with this?

Regards

Comment: Where's the `svc2` in your output coming from? It doesn't exist in your sample data

Comment: `grep -Po 'svc[^ ]*' file` ?

Comment: @anishsane That leaves a `,` after "svc3". `grep -Po 'svc\d'` works though

Comment: Would it be fair to assume that at some point, this data is on separate lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed and grep:

```
sed 's/[^ ]* :\|,\|//g' <<< "$var1" | grep -o '[^ ]*'
```

sed deletes every non-whitespace before a colon and commas. Grep just outputs the resulting services one per line.

Comment: @theuniverseisflat: What do you mean by "does not"?

Comment: means the grep produces nothing .. the first part gets ride of the non-white spaces - that part if fine. when I pipe it and use the grep command .. I get nothing . it lists nothing- blank -- nada - zilch

Comment: @theuniverseisflat: Does your grep support `-o`? Can you run the output of the first part through `xxd` or `hexdump`?

Comment: yes the grep supports the -o option. I used the command as follow echo $var1 | sed 's/[^ ]* :\|,\|//g' <<< "$var1" | grep -o '[^ ]*' .

Comment: @theuniverseisflat: Remove the `echo` part. That's what `<<<` does.

Comment: look I just did this and it works - instead of grep I used a sed command to insert a line where the is a blank. Thx again for ur input  sed "s/ /\n/g"

Answer (score 3):

Using gnu grep and gnu sed:

```
grep -oP ': *\K\w+(, \w+)?' <<< "$var1" | sed 's/, /\n/'
svc1
svc3
svc4
svc5
svc6
```

Answer (score 3):

`grep` is the perfect tool for the job.

From `man grep`:

> -o, --only-matching
>         Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Sounds perfect!

As far as I'm aware this will work on any `grep`:

```
echo "$var1" | grep -o 'svc[0-9]\+'
```

Matches "svc" followed by one or more digits. You can also enable the "highly experimental" Perl regexp mode with `-P`, which means you can use the `\d` digit character class and don't have to escape the `+` any more:

```
grep -Po 'svc\d+' <<<"$var1"
```

In `bash` you can use `<<<` (a *Here String*) which supplies `"$var1"` to `grep` on the standard input.

---

By the way, if your data was originally on separate lines, like:

```
HOST1*prod*gem.dot*serviceList : svc1 
HOST1*prod*kem.dot*serviceList : svc3, svc4    
HOST1*prod*fen.dot*serviceList : svc5, svc6
```

This would be a good job for `awk`:

```
awk -F': ' '{split($2,a,", "); for (i in a) print a[i]}'
```

Comment: not looking for only svc. It can be anything other than svc. Thanks

Comment: No problem. To be honest it looks like you have lines of data coming from elsewhere, with comma separated values after a colon. If that were the case I'd suggest using `awk`. I've added an example showing what I mean above